# How to conditionally set generic type of useState, or remove type `undefined` from state if an initial value is set in custom hook?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, use-state, typescript-generics

I have a custom hook to help with async queries to an API. The hook works similar to a common useState statement in that you can set an initial value or leave it undefined. In the case of the built-in useState statement, the type of the state is no longer undefined when an initial value is specified (e.g. the type changes from (TType | undefined) to (TType)).
In my custom hook, I have an optional parameter for the initial state, but I need to specify the type of the useState in the hook to be (TData | undefined) in case no initiaState is passed in.

But... when an initialState is passed in, I want the type to be only (TData) without the possibility of it being undefined. Otherwise, I need to put checks in place everywhere I use the hook, even when an initial value is set and it will never be undefined.

Is there a way to set the generic type of the useState inside my hook conditionally (i.e. when (initialState !== undefined) then the type is simply (TData), otherwise it is (TData | undefined)?

useAsyncState.ts

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

interface PropTypes<TData> {
  /**
   * Promise like async function
   */
  asyncFunc?: () => Promise<TData>;
  /**
   * Initial data
   */
  initialState?: TData,
}

/**
 * A hook to simplify and combine useState/useEffect statements relying on data which is fetched async.
 * 
 * @example
 *   const { execute, loading, data, error } = useAync({
 *     asyncFunc: async () => { return 'data' },
 *     immediate: false,
 *     initialData: 'Hello'
 *   })
 */
const useAsyncState = <TData>({ asyncFunc, initialState }: PropTypes<TData>, dependencies: any[]) => {
  // The type of useState should no longer have undefined as an option when initialState !== undefined
  const [data, setData] = useState<TData | undefined>(initialState);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>(null);
  const isMounted = useRef<boolean>(true);

  const execute = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!asyncFunc) {
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true)

    try {
      const result = await asyncFunc();

      if (!isMounted.current) {
        return;
      }

      setLoading(false);
      setData(result);
    } catch (err) {
      if (!isMounted.current) {
        return;
      }

      setLoading(false);
      setError(err);
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, [asyncFunc])

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    execute();

    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [...dependencies])

  return {
    execute,
    loading,
    data,
    error,
    setData,
  }
}

export default useAsyncState;
```

using the hook:

```
  // Currently, the type of data is: number[] | undefined
  const { data } = useAsyncState({
    asyncFunc: async (): Promise<number[]> => {
      return [1, 2, 3]
    },
    initialState: [],
  }, []);
```

I assume that the useState hook does something similar to what I want to do here as the type of the state is no longer undefined if an initial value is set with useState.

Comment: My apologies, a leftover from copy and pasting. I am fairly new to posting a question so I am grateful for any advice in relation to my question as well. Thank you!

Comment: You've done an excellent job here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally came up with [something that seemed overcomplicated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDCBDANrgI2wGMBrAGhQwFEAzW9YmStdAJXVpYwGUZsY6SgBFgqMAOIALSj3Qw+A9AEEmwCADs4AXzi0oEEHABEUdCRjGA3ACgbAegBUjm3EdwAKlPRwYATzAfCFo4bDgAA1ZlVD8NYmEBbHC4YjxCElIAOldHext-QLgAVQxo2PjEnHwiMgAeDwT+AD44AF44AAoASjaWgAUDEDF0esbsJtsHZxy4ZTgQbDBAgBNfAJ8YCDh0AA8YKAtfbzXC4LhlxLgwAwA3YGX0VYI-I58Ac2Ab9C1U6oyT9DZNx5Ao+KrpMhjDzrWqYFrtTDbPbfZaoYqlGJxMbgmqkWrADQMKCeMYtAD8JMuAC44Bp0F8oJMnC43J5jmYYMgoFpQXAzpEMeUxuEgbl8ut0SpMRV+AAJCAQUgcTnc2EAIWhgUoDUuCLSuKhMMwGvWTXhiFccCtu0YyEENO6vTgA0Mw1qNwg9wmlqtuAg2GWBLeNIICtw5g0titVou-BpOv4Uej6CgBigNOwGj8SatGBgYxponEkiktTkCn4glUMHUGlGlwAPigNA9aATHmbbNomdNWQB5Bl+gOPPTIOI1zQAvTQV4RKLS4VwKQK0ij8e10UgiUlKVCxLyxVtC3RuD2exwAcpoerADuwBgy7tcAJ9+AeEUgh9cHVmp8u0ELZojuZRYpU+oZLUY6kBoEA3hoTTamMSIAaicA4hkhqBD+ppNB0CDYNKABiY7EJQL41u+lboNoNL4URJE0sav5kRor6UUoZI0mOrbtss2iUA8gQtt8xDAOgqAZlmADaAC6XQ0sBC77iuypcnWTHrIhjbNjxdLLN6J5nmyYhwH6ipoje6DAFAyyUAQT73ku6C4GAFn3lIJxBnAqDIG8bziROGhoh0DxfH6gTErsEViXE6A9IASESJUlyUpfFAB6GWZVlWWpbleWJdlhVFYVdiGeel5QNecB3g+z6sRRuAfugX7YYU-4okBgqgfw6F1FBMFwQhlL8MhHVoeBkKJL+rXoENACS9VvrgSHtYBw3jHhBHlMRcQsWxjVUTRiBbXEO3EIxJpanV+1NTSC37WM-HnOgQkPHEYkSaE0lyQpXUytgB5KvIakzVpzRdj2LLuHMy6Hps3mgGAuDALQLyZqsxCGAQ7ZUOgTX2KwdAMEw3lUSA3wwGiZi4H4XmTrGYQ3lIwDSM+aIMDA0gjidxCinAMwAAK7Ng4DhjMVqY0F8BIDaxB2kIpn+oGGhvAJiSUCmaY6EeUTlHh4vRjzZ0ZtKnQ9K0LRIByalwAA5Azts6OQBtWqA5OBkoNK0HgGDO6yJ7kUtBZ27Kzl+rbBvaF0OR5JLqDwPO5S3ZKIH-YDR6bfRu3XQ1TVHXR20MSnSk9RNeKZn4Q2B+xgicV9fhPYJKIiR9kl+LJ8n106CBfnH8BSQzlB5mMMk67wVEdNXB1KF0OYpJo8dwFJ15BkP8gADJK0Go-tKwTW1KGEDhpmuH7MgcVz33S+a9Aa8wNQqbQDvuP7xXuEaMg+Cz73C-wGIACyEAxyCFWLvDAHBaAHzDBGU+UBz7fytD-KWSJbSCDHlgMuHQeZm27l+AOIQOgAEIjYkR6D3E8FDozW25HPE82g8H80obmDeW8VYdDPhfBhDCrT7BeOQphJ4r5mB8rgeA7RsA3mwI5EhcRui0OjNwihKNOiEIAUAjQIDMhy1TBTMhiiBHUMjPo6M9CBHGOYTATeAYgwdG9rgDACCBHRmHokDowjP4wEcZQ3QqROYeQ6JrPRTjnwENUagQBwDHhaK5GYDRQTglUOBjQ4xpiKHGLzFY5WbxbE+04cEvMD80wBNTF4phccj6Aj9NkwJ8irSpLqZQKSMjiByUtF+Qm9BGAwA6I6C2x4mFqMicsaJOiNFHg4bUlBctBByK4QYpJWhemW3MWzCJGionaNiWIvQuTFH1IoUZcSyMNEAFpAyoGwAQcMJy6R7BOccnwZgLAnNhqQVA9hdhSGwGgGsXwzkvVQF+J6UlMigqbsJd64lWmIJPIY-plDZbyz9kwleKtkWUMHoom+UB0UUJcfwXF3YbBEocOeVo5K4DUB2CLJG4k7BGWUKmbALwaoeSnqTJQNgr5IAZtrMBu44hNX1ieZpJtyhmxpC6IYGBagfxAAQFMsl4TLPmSqLQUkACMlAABMlAADMMkgW4qnsnWSztgVyVsOU8MmQqkhUSN-IyTi0pklJQk3kJk5UKqgLJel55GUHBZe5IBf9Fp4A5Z+blDMaS7G1boflqchUF1OkXbBSzOhSQACzarkhax155gkurdcEj1aIvWKtHk2binBeJ+ovAQAAVl06q7kc5LQjc1KNiQY07D1fG3GiaJ7JuIMbUIpt014S+qgSy6Y4DZp0F0PaucqK0SnTOmk2qADsOg822Cdc611+6BGluOkFddtJkDypTPQt1fZG3NtZSGtt4b46cq7XGJEmb+2J0FUO0VY7xUTvwmelMNJs1R13cWg9UHj0ShMsB6doGL1XqgLoKtwk2x6TrQAOUvd6lttV2Wvsjb-RA0akQAFZv1-STf+tN5sWjZqXUtZOW7INHqYUWjjlCT3lqgDhvDKYCOPlDftDtXLSMIHI7sAAbNRgVxBaNZ3OgBuIOC+ngcaZamDnHD0FqcbxwTxJ0O6UeDYIAA) so I asked [Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) to look it over. He was able to simplify it (as I suspected). It turns out the key was something I'd done quite late in the process of building my original: Using `& {initialState?: undefined}` in one of two overload signatures to add in `undefined` to the possible types that the `data` member of the returned object could have.

Here's the result, with explanatory comments. There's an assumption in there: That you want the `setData` function **not** to accept `undefined` even when there's no `initialState` (and so `TData` has `undefined` in it). But there are instructions for removing that if you want `setData` to accept `TData` (even when it includes `undefined`).

```typescript
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

interface PropTypes<TData> {
    /**
     * Promise like async function
     */
    asyncFunc?: () => Promise<TData>;
    /**
     * Initial data
     */
    initialState?: TData,
}

/**
 * The return type of `useAsyncData`.
 */
type UseAsyncDataHookReturn<TData, TSetData extends TData = TData> = {
    // The `TSetData` type is so that we can allow `undefined` in `TData` but not in `TSetData` so
    // `setData` doesn't allow `undefined`. If you don't need that, just do this:
    // 1. Remove `TSetData` above
    // 2. Use `TData` below where `TSetData` is
    // 3. In the "without" overload in the function signature below, remove the second type argument
    //    in `UseAsyncDataHookReturn` (at the end).
    execute: () => Promise<void>;
    loading: boolean;
    data: TData;
    error: any;
    setData: Dispatch<SetStateAction<TSetData>>;
};

/**
 * An overloaded function type for `useAsyncData`.
 */
interface UseAsyncDataHook {
    // The "without" signature adds `& { initialState?: undefined }` to `ProptTypes<TData>` to make
    // `initialState` optional, and adds `| undefined` to the type of the `data` member of the returned object.
    <TData>({ asyncFunc, initialState }: PropTypes<TData> & { initialState?: undefined }, dependencies: any[]): UseAsyncDataHookReturn<TData | undefined, TData>;
    // The "with" signature just uses `ProptTypes<TData>`, so `initialState` is required and is type `TData`,
    // and the type of `data` in the returned object doesn't have `undefined`, it's just `TData`.
    <TData>({ asyncFunc, initialState }: PropTypes<TData>, dependencies: any[]): UseAsyncDataHookReturn<TData>;
}

/**
 * A hook to simplify and combine useState/useEffect statements relying on data which is fetched async.
 * 
 * @example
 *   const { execute, loading, data, error } = useAync({
 *     asyncFunc: async () => { return 'data' },
 *     immediate: false,
 *     initialData: 'Hello'
 *   })
 */
const useAsyncState: UseAsyncDataHook = <TData,>({ asyncFunc, initialState }: PropTypes<TData>, dependencies: any[])  => {
// Only need this comma in .tsx files −−−−−−−−^
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialState);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // *** No need for a type argument in most cases
    const [error, setError] = useState<any>(null); // *** But there is here :-)
    const isMounted = useRef(true);
  
    const execute = useCallback(async () => {
        if (!asyncFunc) {
            return;
        }
      
        setLoading(true);
      
        try {
            const result = await asyncFunc();
        
            if (!isMounted.current) {
                return;
            }
        
            setLoading(false);
            setData(result);
        } catch (err) {
          if (!isMounted.current) {
              return;
          }
      
          setLoading(false);
          setError(err);
          console.log(err);
        }
    }, [asyncFunc]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
        isMounted.current = true;
        execute();
      
        return () => {
            isMounted.current = false;
        };
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [...dependencies]);
  
    return {
        execute,
        loading,
        data,
        error,
        setData,
    };
};

// === Examples

// Array with initial state
const { data, setData } = useAsyncState({
    asyncFunc: async (): Promise<number[]> => {
        return [1, 2, 3]
    },
    initialState: [],
}, []);
console.log(data);
//          ^?
//           type is number[]
console.log(setData);
//          ^?
//          type is Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>>

// Array without initial state
const {data: data2, setData: setData2} = useAsyncState({asyncFunc: async () => ([42])}, []);
console.log(data2);
//          ^?
//           type is number[] | undefined
console.log(setData2);
//          ^?
//          type is Dispatch<SetStateAction<number[]>> -- notice that it doesn't allow setting `undefined`

// Object with initial state
const {data: data3, setData: setData3} = useAsyncState({asyncFunc: async () => ({ answer: 42 }), initialState: { answer: 27 }}, []);
console.log(data3);
//          ^?
//           type is {answer: number;}
console.log(setData3);
//          ^?
//          type is Dispatch<SetStateAction<{answer: number;}>>

// Object without initial state
const {data: data4, setData: setData4} = useAsyncState({asyncFunc: async () => ({answer: 42})}, []);
console.log(data4);
//          ^?
//           type is {answer: number} | undefined
console.log(setData4);
//          ^?
//          type is Dispatch<SetStateAction<{answer: number;}>> -- again, notice it doesn't allow `undefined`

// Number with initial state
const {data: data5, setData: setData5} = useAsyncState({asyncFunc: async () => 42, initialState: 27}, []);
console.log(data5);
//          ^?
//           type is number
console.log(setData5);
//          ^?
//          type is Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>

// Number without initial state
const {data: data6, setData: setData6} = useAsyncState({asyncFunc: async () => 42}, []);
console.log(data6);
//          ^?
//           type is number | undefined
console.log(setData6);
//          ^?
//          type is Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>> -- and again, doesn't allow `undefined`
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDCBDANrgI2wGMBrAGhQwFEAzW9YmStdAJXVpYwGUZsY6SgBFgqMAOIALSj3Qw+A9AEEmwCADs4AXzi0oEEHABEUdCRjGA3ACgbwDYKi0S6OAAUDYACoBPMOioADzewgLYAHyINnCxcAD0AFSJMXFwiR4GIGJuuMCkbtiovhrEesilMOoaqXGJ8bVwRSXEAGIVxAD8AFxwABQAlHAAvFGehjkhYfwRtmlJKWnpcACSGsBVeHAAJuGN6Q1pDhvAeIqCPXCh4eQ22nYLMRneUm5mMMhQWjD+bhC0cAABqxlMVStNsICAHRPBo-AJwACqGFBLQhAAkIBBSBwPl8pjcrnIYBC4OgAB6CDTbVBXUnDOnhKIMhCNeLxK6vIHeYkQwFweFuMRwVAQAVSARwADubmI2C0eFwEClQIq204DnQ235Dm5fLgBGQ8A0EHgusBPPk+tFbI5gIwJPC-O2EECGgA5PBFcrVdSNRotdDVgDfBBkDtNJ64AGteKBJQAFZoeAu8Vibq2uAARihcA4IAgADc3BbeU6mgQi+hMwAmXPIkvXfj8gjoJUqqWvMzcsvNuBiTMAZlza3FbmMUo2UjDljgVagSuw2373y5tA6VU0IuAAHMNAJPm5W+3KGYC8WxyLGJpl4KmlAd8gQOhHJm4uaG6jweFMdjcZ8NH5PpJRgLkX22AYYTSClGCNdBekGEYxiySZCwgYBtlmRpF22Bwd16SsIFwcwNDmOJdn4Xom2wMjYnQKADCgXp5V8Wir0dSi4FEcRJCkIJiXOFQ1E0EJe0iLDtFsGxHmWZQtHnHDY3XSpqgFX49GgVUUTBYg+Sg+p7EceiXGINxPx0jEsVIaJ5g5F5x0nUCZ2Mbc9wPbslxpIEADJEBXE4zn4C5ejVf1Y20fkYDFQFxjAGA-ACYJqIiSKxRAbACkzQFjk2XBBP5CA4uqPBKHlZdPNpQEAB8UD9WhNW1AUxVAtw73+S9AQoyE4GfEBWygOcARauB3gA2MIAIBNGBgKC4gJGY+iQZpSnaUpKBy048qCtxtF6WKEsCebIjgXykA2wKlEuUL6oDZdtEodUAj9UpgECZiNF8ABtABdAZenMtEfys-98WouAauuhrKGStj2U5Bypxc1Bd33PE3CTVB4FYSrYvi34kohFLKFFIFzq2pQdVpMwAEdkGAMxyupftaTvC0+VuWymiZ4a2oBTry11YbRq+cbJumiM3SjCUL2BOqGsBdaYHdWkMfgNmnVm2IjoiRamh01biHW9ZcsEnQ9q8A6CaZB70Ce9UXrermvt+-7tMB-hfxxeQAO12x7mk5InjgZQ4GnbEmu3cA8loXwueXYhDAITUqHQQT4lYOgGCYEVtufRwqbbXw8LnLQuulKRgGkZm9HkaRY2W4h9LgIOAAEKWwKPq2WWIE40TG-Jg4g4MoHC8Iewl6MYnQRhT5QWkWoO0gbg3mJ0-ohlGPzha0d0uvdHQOYyI4QGfXClF6FxcAwQ+ljJiFenddE2yVd1F50AZYRsXv+5BHTBNdlQFkgbhwZEdcgOslr6w6EbAK5NBBm0yIVS22sbZ2xfMQV6qB3rOyGEhaIcMADyGhcCxxjLeCutIE4n2wCuOAUIYCoHJHoYAxFaSACQiDhnCOEAD1Gjf3gJ9LqxMrThG+jPVggk+hk0EgMNi-C4CfVHhoHcwiYAABkIBLjwmIhkEjtp9BgFAZA6BZEJA5MkDIAA5MUZCNIDRoXebAD4nwvjNFoAs-c5QYFQHwzQ-dPqT2gKo6gDFoA6JToJIILEdYaGQPgUxcMLFwAAEJGjHN2YUXY3DdAALQfzSPIsQABZMMRlly6IwBwWgBijEmLIr4vu8BB5wXERgHA+AiBkGAmvRCm9WRLHfACPoABCZeHQhj9IGUsbebE0j3AGfsOIDoNFaOUTU4xsjFmLNiIY2OkyplxHkWYVAcT4AMmwFKbAGw9YtANoMWZcRtm3yGcM4ppTBDbChEPBiriJlPIOTM-5cR5lTKBbEZZmjcJrMvhgTZBy0gOghH0Y5py4VTN0HKGAVc+iTz+fC-sLy3kVA+V8z4ZhHB4vxXEQF+KQVpCBRC1ZO4+gwrqQy+QITGI4oYmig538iLoChEqZluKHmxDpQfBRYzSi-XqWkDO9Bpp9F6VEfZt9UAlOJVqUlPzHAz0McYsVZJySwUEPcrZALvZfHXngtVByiVlJ1eSs5eg8AYCNZJJ5cNAh5EcDk3CqBsAEGIjkgMlIcm+reOYJgOSw6kFQPECkEpkzAGLP622Pi5mUE+lCXNj1wLoMwbK1IjRt42Smc0wQHMplKJUU8oRTzAlQGrQMxFNxGies9dJDkwxe1wGoOSDuYBWEPA5MoBi2BY6OSkP5XKOclBfz8fAJAQj2Kkl0BUwBLRJFqulcQVeLR17mwmBgIIsS+r0R+syVVTyy2fSzJQGslBBzfQ7S22dm1-4KO+rce637Nn8uIkKiAzKuqbLhvC7hnRu1UrvMKc9-UfqLr7gK4DzK238HAxySD0GIMHLg7SbiEgsV8QEttVQm4NBnqfIh76EQIijuDhOqdU4Zwfq2JjBd8iEBdV6F1J9a7wi9Aw9gGsG7Z5-30QgPdB7Sg2s3n0T6AAWGsv0-0-QA341Dwq+j8aw-iqDMH8UEejDRy9YiIZy1ush0UQGdMiZrPpnDRn8PqWFER3i-F5CCQo9UajF6oBXqiDknJ0ZTSV1ahKM0KZXSoA9F6fAPoHRVGUb6dUN1AyMYIWLbO072O4HnYIGzy7eM7HCIOVR99BP8EHOJ3+26pMyZuXJlV-Qlp9xlExOAKn34wJNttXo7XUCdd6DWAA7DodTxbAOCp011QcTmDmGbw65hEwppMdfor0BD9ErD3Bm2hvoImFu2BWwM5b2HVtCkI2IYj0gvMKHI8JKjG3htbdMwFvb9Gss5fgNOtjZNCvVm46VrqSnKtCeq9gJTdW3alB3U1hu8moiLXlG9rrKntADCm5plDdmQO6fCEpxbUyLuwbc7SV7I2Pv9V0JZ9LDUbPaYJyJ4np3Luk9wxzgZJmPMkYez557QQqfvZ21AL7wXQvYB3FcjQlATRVFMv2GLksEvtjS2FbUjHLFmYGnlwHnGisg8h11AArBDziInTew63fDxrUDSiybKK1lTfXP0DbgONnHtgDtzfCKbkn52ufk7W7SMXTP8foZEfwAP7ODPB-hbz27nmyNKF8yJMX32YM64C9KVjaSDfbWK4gUH4QABsFvsDCej9gMvNuvzEARw7-dzXncbyiJj7N02tOR8J-wMvgelhk+MxTmn9Fwa1QZ9Z33LOa8D7j85s7Swk88X56nwQ6eqOZ8l3HJoMuHAPVi-FpoiWVSyyn5loAA)

Comment: (Not sure why the syntax highlighting cuts out midway through the code block...)

Comment: That works great, thank you! And thanks for explaining it so clearly as well!